# How to load images in the same folder in Pytorch?

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I want to load all of the images from the folder `/img` and `/mask` respectively. The data structure can be shown as follows:

```
data
    img
        0.png
        1.png
        2.png
        3.png
        ...
   mask
       label_0.png
       label_1.png
       label_2.png
       ...
```

Hopefully for help.

Comment: where do you want to load the images, do you want to load images from one folder to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load all the images from the two folders then you can try cv2

```
import cv2

img = []
for i in range(n): # n = number of images in img folder
    img_path = f'~data\img\{i}.png' # replace ~ with full path 
    img.append(cv2.imread(img_path))

for i in range(n): # n = number of images in mask folder
    img_path = f'~data\mask\lable_{i}.png' # replace ~ with full path
    img.append(cv2.imread(img_path))
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way, can I use `DataLoader` or other class to load it and how? I want to input the images in multiple threads.

Comment: check out the links if it helps [how_do_i_load_images_into_pytorch_for_training](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/92nh4c/how_do_i_load_images_into_pytorch_for_training/) or [how-do-you-load-images-into-pytorch-dataloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052295/how-do-you-load-images-into-pytorch-dataloader)

Answer (score 1):

If your Python is 3.4+, 
You can get the file list which has the same extension name using `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path
# *.png
result = list( Path('./data/').rglob('*.[pP][nN][gG]') )
print(result)
```

Outcome:

```
[PosixPath('data/img/0.png'),
 PosixPath('data/img/0.png'),
 PosixPath('data/img/0.png'),
 ...
 PosixPath('data/mask/label_0.png'),
 PosixPath('data/mask/label_1.png'),
 PosixPath('data/mask/label_2.png'),
 ...
]
```